# UUID as _id in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, uuid

I've found multiple sites saying using UUID is possible, but not how. I've tried to simply have a "_id" property that is a UUID, but when I use postman to get the object the "_id" field says null.
[Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw5Ni.png)
I've made sure mongodb knows UUID by specifying it in the settings:

```
`

import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.*;

import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;

import com.mongodb.client.model.FindOneAndReplaceOptions;
import com.mongodb.client.model.ReturnDocument;
import de.tudo.ls14.aqua.smarthome.model.Device;
import de.tudo.ls14.aqua.smarthome.model.Household;
import de.tudo.ls14.aqua.smarthome.model.User;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.UuidRepresentation;
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.PojoCodecProvider;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromProviders;
import static org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.fromRegistries;

@Repository("Mongodao")
public class MongoDao {
    final MongoClient mongoClient;
    final MongoDatabase mongoDatabase;
    final MongoCollection<User> userCollection;
    final MongoCollection<Household> householdCollection;
    final MongoCollection<Device> deviceCollection;


    public MongoDao() {
        String password = System.getProperty("password");//Passwort aus den VM options
        Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.ALL);
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("someConnectionString");
        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), pojoCodecRegistry);
        MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD)
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                .build();

        mongoClient = MongoClients.create(clientSettings);

        mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("ProjektDB");
        userCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("userCollection", User.class);
        householdCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("householdCollection", Household.class);
        deviceCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("deviceCollection", Device.class);
    }

    public User getUserById(UUID id) {
        return userCollection.find(eq("id", id)).first();
    }

    public Household getHouseholdById(UUID id) {
        return householdCollection.find(eq("id", id)).first();
    }

    public Device getDeviceById(UUID id) {
        return deviceCollection.find(eq("id", id)).first();
    }

    public int addHousehold(Household household) {
        householdCollection.insertOne(household);
        return 1;
    }

    public int addUser(User user) {
        userCollection.insertOne(user);
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> added:"+user.toString());
        return 1;
    }

    public int addDevice(Device device) {
        deviceCollection.insertOne(device);
        return 1;
    }

    public User updateUserById(User user) {
        Document filterByUserId = new Document("_id", user.get_id());
        FindOneAndReplaceOptions returnDocAfterReplace = new FindOneAndReplaceOptions().returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER);
        return userCollection.findOneAndReplace(filterByUserId, user, returnDocAfterReplace);
    }

    //nur zum testen
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        MongoCursor<User> cursor = userCollection.find().iterator();
        List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            while(cursor.hasNext()){
                userList.add(cursor.next());
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return userList;
    }
}
`
```

Funny enough when i check with ATLAS it even says the _id field is an objectid [as seen here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0ggZ.png)
I've printed my object out and it is clear that the _id field is UUID [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw0ZM.png).
For the sake of it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iui0W.png) is also shown that my pojo certainly uses UUID for the _id field. I'm out of ideas.
Do I have to specify things differently?

Comment: We don’t know how you’re inserting the data, and there are about a thousand steps between Mongo and Postman. Can you provide more details?

Comment: ^ what are the exact documents being inserted?

Comment: Hi, hope thats how to answer. I'm using a basic springboot webserver, I've printed the objects i'm inserting and they certainly use UUID for their _id field. I try to put the whole DAO into my post

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a `@BsonProperty("_id")` annotation to the UUID property in the POJO because it was just `private UUID id = IdUtils.newId();` Not `_id`.

To query using the java driver:

```
import org.bson.Document;

public User findUserById(final UUID id){
 return collection.find(new Document("_id", id)).first();
}
```